# Error in executing a python function from a javascript code using flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

I have am running a `python` `flask` application and from the `html` page I am calling a `javascript` file(using `<script src=....>`). Here is my `html` file:

**HTML FILE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="static/chat/js/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="require.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="speech.css">

</head>

<body>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <nav class="navbar-left" height="100" style="background-color: #092A66 !important;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" padding-top=0 padding-bottom=0 href="#">
        <img src="image.jpg"  height="100" alt="">
      </a>

    </nav>
 <br><br>

 <div class="container">
                <div id="chat" class="jumbotron" style="height:600px;background-color:white">
                    <div id="conversations" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:500px;overflow:auto; ">
                          <div class="arrow"></div>
                              <ul class="ChatLog">
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="compose-message">
                        <label for="new-input-message">{{gettext('Message')}}</label>
                        <input type="text" id="new-input-message" class="speech-input" aria-describedby="new-input-message-help-block" name="eng-input" lang = "en" disabled="false">
                        <small id="new-input-message-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                          {{gettext('Hit enter to send message')}}
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
<script src="static/speech-in.js"></script>   
<script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function()
{

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

// OTHER IMPORTANT CODE FOR FURTHER PROCESSING
 .
 . 
 .
});

</script>
```

In the above code I am including the `socket.io` in the `head` of the `html` file and then I am including `speech-in.js` file in which I want to use socket connection. My current code in `speech-in.js` is:

**speech-in.js:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // check for support (webkit only)
    if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) return;

    var talkMsg = 'Speak now';
    // seconds to wait for more input after last
    var defaultPatienceThreshold = 6;

    function capitalize(str) {
        return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
    }
    console.log('Check 1');
    var inputEls = document.getElementsByClassName('speech-input');

    [].forEach.call(inputEls, function(inputEl) {
        var patience = parseInt(inputEl.dataset.patience, 10) || defaultPatienceThreshold;
        var micBtn, micIcon, holderIcon, newWrapper;
        var shouldCapitalize = true;

        // gather inputEl data
        var nextNode = inputEl.nextSibling;
        var parent = inputEl.parentNode;
        var inputRightBorder = parseInt(getComputedStyle(inputEl).borderRightWidth, 10);
        var buttonSize = 0.8 * (inputEl.dataset.buttonsize || inputEl.offsetHeight);

        // default max size for textareas
        if (!inputEl.dataset.buttonsize && inputEl.tagName === 'TEXTAREA' && buttonSize > 26) {
            buttonSize = 26;
        }

        // create wrapper if not present
        var wrapper = inputEl.parentNode;
        if (!wrapper.classList.contains('si-wrapper')) {
            wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            wrapper.classList.add('si-wrapper');
            wrapper.appendChild(parent.removeChild(inputEl));
            newWrapper = true;
        }
        console.log('Check 2');
        // create mic button if not present
        micBtn = wrapper.querySelector('.si-btn');
        if (!micBtn) {
            micBtn = document.createElement('button');
            micBtn.type = 'button';
            micBtn.classList.add('si-btn');
            micBtn.textContent = 'speech input';
            micIcon = document.createElement('span');
            holderIcon = document.createElement('span');
            micIcon.classList.add('si-mic');
            holderIcon.classList.add('si-holder');
            micBtn.appendChild(micIcon);
            micBtn.appendChild(holderIcon);
            wrapper.appendChild(micBtn);

            // size and position mic and input
            micBtn.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            micBtn.style.top = 0.125 * buttonSize + 'px';
            micBtn.style.height = micBtn.style.width = buttonSize + 'px';
            inputEl.style.paddingRight = buttonSize - inputRightBorder + 'px';
        }

        // append wrapper where input was
        if (newWrapper) parent.insertBefore(wrapper, nextNode);

        console.log('Check 3');

        // GOING TO CALL PYTHON FUNCTION

        $( document ).ready(function(){


        //Receive a new message
        socket.on('speech', function(msg) {
        var time = new Date();
        time_str = time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })
             new_msg='<li class="ChatLog__entry"> <img class="ChatLog__avatar" src="static/chat/images/Assistant.png" /> <p class="ChatLog__message"> '+msg+' <time class="ChatLog__timestamp">'+time_str+'</time> </p> </li>'

             $("#conversations ul").append(new_msg)
             $('#new-input-message').prop('disabled', false);

            });

        });

});
    console.log('Check 4');
})();
```

As you can see I am making use of `socket.on` but it throws error because `socket` is `unrecognizable`. I am including the `socket.io` class in my `html` file and I am establishing a connection to it also in the `html` file but that connection is not visible in this `javascript` file.

I also have the python flask application executing which has a function with route `@socket.on('speech')` qualified to it.

What mistake I am making here and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

`socket` object is not available in your `speech-in.js` file since it is not in global scope.

All `socket` events should be subscribed to in callback after `connect` event received:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

socket.on('connect', function() {

   // subscribe to events here
   socket.on('custom_event_from_flask', function (data) {
      console.log('Event received data:' + JSON.stringify(data));
   });
});
```

One of the options is to move socket initialization into your `speech-in.js` file from `index.html`. However, if you expect your project to grow it would be better to change client side (JS) to have it more logically organized using at least [JS es6 modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).

Comment: If I move the above code to my `speech-in.js` file then will it be available in html file as well because in my html file too I am using socket connection for other processing?

Comment: You can modify your speech-in.js and create a JS module and pass socket variable as a parameter.

Comment: can you show that as an example on how can I create the JS module and pass parameter to it?

Comment: There are some examples available https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples so just follow them. If you are thinking about restructuring your project look into the basics of JS modules first http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_modules-in-javascript.